# View empty cart WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a way to view the cart page when you have an empty cart?

I'm using a save-for-later plugin but if your cart is empty you cannot view the cart page.

I'd like to allow the user to still access the cart page rather than getting the empty car message.

Comment: You could develop the blank cart template instead for redirect to the cart page. There is a [tutorial](https://divi.space/wordpress-and-divi-code-snippets/customize-woocommerce-empty-shopping-cart-page/) for customise empty cart page yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First add this to your child theme `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Load cart template anytime withouth any empty cart check
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_items_action', 1 );
function woocommerce_check_cart_items_action() {
    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();

    wc_get_template( 'cart/cart.php' );
}
```

Now you need to remove the empty cart message by changing the `cart-empty.php` template. For overwriting templates read this:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

In your case you need to create a `woocommerce` folder in your child theme root folder. After that you need to create another folder inside your new `woocommerce` folde named `cart`. In this folder create a file `cart-empty.php` with the following content:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
```

That's it. When you now visit your cart page, you'll see you cart, but it's empty. If this makes sense is another question.